# TAP::Formatter::HTML - Redirecting output of generated HTML to a file

Tags: html, perl, formatter, tap

I'm using the TAP::Formatter::HTML module from CPAN in Perl/Windoes. I notice that there is an option that allows us to redirect the HTML output in a file viz. output_file().

However, I think I'm missing something.

I tried using $fmt->output_file($outputfile) but to no avail.

It gives me the following error:
Can't locate object method "output_fh" via package "TAP::Formatter::HTML" at tap
.pl line 12.

Could someone tell me what am I missing?
A sample code that explains how to redirect the output would be ideal.

I checked a post by a user named "knb" who seems to have worked with this module. 
I hope he reads this as well.

Thanks!

CODE:

```
use TAP::Harness;
use IO::Handle;
use TAP::Formatter::HTML;
use File::Glob::Windows;
use TAP::Parser::Aggregator;

my $fmt = TAP::Formatter::HTML->new;

my @tests = glob( 'te*.pl');
my $harness = TAP::Harness->new( { formatter => $fmt, merge => 1 } );

$fmt->output_file('output.html');

$harness->runtests(@tests);
```

Comment: out.html I'm updating my original post with the code.

Comment: knb here. Thanks for mentioning me. 

However, I don't have time to lookup my code right now. I usually run my test scripts on linux. Will get back to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit of problems to install it on Windows (needed to skip tests to proceed), but your simplified script works for me:

```
use TAP::Harness;
use TAP::Formatter::HTML;

my $fmt = TAP::Formatter::HTML->new;
my $harness = TAP::Harness->new( { formatter => $fmt, merge => 1 } );
$fmt->output_file('output.html');

$harness->runtests('1.t');
```

This built `output.html` file with test results. It however did not properly include javascripts and css files.